# Should link content be summarized in the answer?

Tags: discussion

In [one of the answers](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/1735/945) i proposed to [Michael Dorfman](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/463/michael-dorfman) to expand his answer by summarizing the content by the link he provided. He answered, that

> trying to summarize a work of philosophy as concise as that is a fool's errand.

My questions are then:

- Should answers containing a link also summarize its content per [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/170363)?
- If **yes**, what should be the proper size and content of the summary to be both succinct and faithful to the original meaning?
- If **no**, what are the reasons not to summarize the philosophical works in answers?
- If **sometimes**, what are the criteria when the content should be summarized?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "sometimes"; it of course depends on the context whether a link-only answer really answers the question...

Answer (score 2):

The ***best*** answers referring to other material will summarize the content, at least briefly. However, this is not *required* and not always feasible depending on the state of the content and the expertise of the answerer.

For example, there are many areas of philosophy that I've read on the surface level, and I can provide sources in those areas to people, but I lack the expertise to summarize them effectively in any reasonable amount of time (I would have to spend a week rereading the text, jotting down notes, re-familiarizing myself with the terms, etc.). It's simply not practical, and yet being able to provide a short answer referring to a text is still in many cases better than nothing. In my case, I would hope that someone who knows the material better could edit my answer and insert a brief explanation (people seem to forget they can suggest-edit answers *as well as* questions!). :P

So in regards to your question here, the answer is "only if a person wants to". Those answers which are otherwise equal **but one has a summary and the other does not** will naturally be voted up appropriately, and I think that works pretty well on our site. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, no surprise what my opinion is here.

> Should answers containing a link also summarize its content per *Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?*?

I think the key factor here is that what I was providing was not merely a link, but a reference to a classic philosophical work on the subject.  I could have answered just as easily without the link, by mentioning only the author and title of the piece, but since it was available online, I provided that as well.

> If yes, what should be the proper size and content of the summary to be both succinct and faithful to the original meaning?

I think this depends largely on two factors: the narrowness of the question, and the scope of the philosophical work referred to.

If somebody asked a very narrow question about a very large book (say, the difference between the intuition of a manifold and a manifold of intuition in Kant's Critique of Pure Reason), an adequate answer would require a summary or paraphrase.  In this case, however, the question was very broad ("What is existentialism?") and the text in question is very short (just a few pages, **aimed at answering that particular question**) so a paraphrase would require answering the question more succinctly than Sartre was able to do, which seems unlikely.

So: yes, by all means, we should summarize as a general rule, when possible.  But, when people are asking questions that have already been answered clearly in the literature, I think a pointer to the canonical reference is suitable.

Anyway, that's my story, and I'm sticking to it.